# Only change layout on a certain condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout

In my gem I only want to change the layout on a certain condition.

I know I can have a method for specifying the layout, but how can I point to the current layout in that method? I've learned that `_layout` points to the layout name, but it causes a stack overflow if it's called in the method that specifies the layout.

Here's my code for clarification (In my engine's application controller):

```
layout :get_layout

def get_layout

  current = _layout # this is what I want, but causes a stack overflow
  request.path_info.include?( '/baco/' ) ? 'baco' : current

end
```

So for example: The application with this gem specifies a layout called 'qday', now the gem needs to change the layout if the path includes 'baco', but if it doesn't, it should render 'qday'.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you seem to be trying to do is always setting the layout, and if you don't want to change it, setting it to what it already was.  Instead, because of the recursion, I think you should only set the layout if your condition holds.

```
before_filter set_baco_layout

def set_baco_layout
  self.class.layout "baco" if request.path_info.include?( '/baco/' )
end
```

It would be a cleaner design, however, if your engine controllers each called layout.

```
class Baco::BatsController < ApplicationController
  layout "baco"
  ...
```

That might not seem DRY, but it is a step cleaner.

To fix the DRY thing, I'd used inheritance.  Have a base controller class which sets the layout and inherit your other controllers from your base.

```
class Baco::BaseController < ApplicaitonController
  layout "baco"
end

class Baco::BatsController < Baco::BaseContoller
  ...
```

Comment: Great, this method works for me, thanks! As commented on jdoe, the per-controller method isn't working for me in this situation. Because I need two layouts for one controller that controls two devise models. The path condition is the only way I found to separate the two.

Comment: If you need more than one layout for the same controller, then call render in the method with the :layout => "baco" option for the actions which need it.

Comment: 1) `before_filter set_baco_layout` -- I guess `set_baco_layout` should be a symbol; 2) using `self.class.layout` leads to a HUGE pitfall: once you set layout it will be used further even if there is no `baco` in the url -- who's gonna be resetting it to its defaults?

Comment: Good point.  I'd still go with setting it for the whole controller at a time, or in the render of each action which needs it.

Comment: This is a controller that extends devise. The controller has no actions at all. It just needs to verify which user type is currently in focus, and than render the admin layout for admins and the application layout for users. Because admins always sign in at the `baco` path. I'm still facing issues, because the layout seems to be cached, after signing in as an admin and trying to sign in as a user, it still renders the admin layout.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
before_filter only: [:index, :show, :edit, :new] do
  render layout: 'baco' if request.path_info.include? '/baco/'
end
```

BTW, Rails allows you to use per-controller layouts without coding. Just name it after your controller but w/o `controller` at the end (like `users.html.haml`) and put it to your `/views/layouts/` dir. Just for consideration...

Comment: Great method! Gives me a lot of more usability for the before filter.. Thanks for the controller method, but it wouldn't work for me because the baco path is a devise admins path, and the condition is used to render different layouts for admins and users, both using devise controllers..

Comment: Oops, little problem, after testing I found that my devise/sessions/create view wasn't found anymore..

Comment: I guess you don't know about constraints for filters. I changed answer. Check it now.